# hook for loading page

Tags: hooks

I wanted to load my custom plugin when the "Jobs" page is loaded. How am I able to do it?
This is my code so far.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: wp-retrieve-database
 * Description: retrieves data from the database.
 * Version: 0.5
 * Author: Chan */

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Careers";
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    function get_scrapy_scraped(){
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>Location/Dept</th>
    <th>Complete Info</th>
    <th>Application Link<th>
    </tr>
        foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){
        <tr>
        <td>echo $retrieved_data->Job_Name;</td>
        <td>echo $retrieved_data->Job_Department;</td>
        <td>echo $retrieved_data->Job_Link_Info;</td>
        <td>echo $retrieved_data->Job_Link_Apply;</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    }
add_action('dont know what to be used', 'get_scrapy_scraped');  
?>
```

Comment: Where is the jobs page, in the front or admin, how is it loaded?

Comment: Im kinda new to worpress but this is the site... http://www.southjerseyrn.com/jobs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `the_content` and check if `is_page( 'jobs' )` is `TRUE`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'get_scrapy_scraped' );

function get_scrapy_scraped( $content )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_page( 'jobs' ) )
        return $content;

    $table_name    = $wpdb->prefix . "Careers";
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );

    if ( ! $retrieve_data )
        return $content;

    $table = '<table><tr>
    <th>Job Name</th>
    <th>Location/Dept</th>
    <th>Complete Info</th>
    <th>Application Link<th>
    </tr>';

    foreach ( $retrieve_data as $row )
    {
        $table .= "<tr>
            <td>{$row->Job_Name}</td>
            <td>{$row->Job_Department}</td>
            <td>{$row->Job_Link_Info}</td>
            <td>{$row->Job_Link_Apply}</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    $table .= "</table>";

    return $table . $content;
}
```